# Internacionalização, L10n e I18N

Tags: php, i18n, internacionalização

Segundo a **w3**, no que diz respeito a *L10n* e *I18N*, separei a explicação abaixo que vai servir como base para ilustrar minhas dúvidas.

<sub>**L10n** [[ **fonte** ]](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n#l10n)</sub>

> Geralmente considerada apenas como um sinônimo de tradução de uma interface gráfica ou documentação, a localização é substancialmente muito mais complexa. Ela pode implicar na personalização relacionada a:
>
> 1. Formatos de data, hora e números
> 2. Uso da moeda
> 3. Verificação e classificação
> 4. Símbolos, ícones e cores
> 5. Textos e gráficos que, em determinada cultura, podem estar sujeitos a erros de interpretação
> 6. Variação dos requisitos legais

<sub>**I18n** [[ **fonte** ]](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n#i18n)</sub>

> A internacionalização é a criação e o desenvolvimento de um produto, aplicação ou conteúdo de um documento que permite a localização fácil para públicos-alvo que variam em cultura, região ou idioma.
>
> 1. Inclusão de suporte às preferências locais, regionais, culturais ou de idiomas. Normalmente, isso envolve a inserção pré-definida de dados de localização e recursos derivados de bibliotecas disponíveis ou de preferências do usuário. Exemplos incluem: formatos de data e hora, calendários locais, formatos de números e sistemas numéricos, classificação e apresentação de listas, manipulação de nomes pessoais, formas de endereço etc..

---

Muitos exemplos e explicações limitam a *internacionalização* apenas para tradução de pacotes de idioma e formatação horária e monetária. Mesmo que se faça o uso correto e amplo da i18n, ela estará sempre relacionada com a composição visual relacionada com a view, exibindo o conteúdo formatado para o idioma escolhido pelo usuário?

Sobre a *localização*, me parece que além de manter uma relação com a view, ela pode influenciar controllers e models, como nos exemplos n. 3, 5 e 6. L10n pode ter influência e personalizar o conteúdo que será exibido - está correto? Nesse caso, também seria baseado no idioma escolhido pelo usuário ou na regionalização do conteúdo em questão?

Procuro por algum pattern [PHP] a algum tempo mas só encontro exemplos separados, e L10n é quase inexistente. Minha I18n provê a tradução do sistema e formatação na view sem problemas, mas agora preciso ter gerência sobre o conteúdo dinâmico de acordo em a geolocalização, e creio que seja responsabilidade da L10n. Não quero uma classe multiuso nem quebrar padrão.

Comment: Essa até eu quero ver. Meu pacotinho de tradução simplesmente lê um arquivo .MO gerado a partir de um .PO, gera um array e bora. Agora fazer a coisa certa, do jeito certo é que são elas.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, por isso dei a base da explicação, mas ainda há outras opções como a *globalização*. O meu i18n trabalha com `vsprintf` onde posso formatar de acordo com o pacote. Acho que abrange alguns pontos da i18n, mas não faço ponte com a l10n, o que pode limitar o uso de ambos.

Comment: O l10n está em desuso pois é menos amplo que o i18n. No l10n você se importava com poucos aspectos , somente mesmo em traduzir texto e exibir moeda, data no formato do pais. 
A i18n é mais ampla e está sendo mais utilizada, você leva em consideração o conjunto de caracter (exemplo japonês, chinês), a forma de escrita ( direita - esquerda, esquerda - direita, cima - baixo ) e ajustar resources (imagens video, audio ) para a localização do usuário. Os textos colocados são muito mais teoricos do que práticos.

Answer (score 3):

**Internacionalização (i18n)**: é o processo de desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que pode ser adaptada a vários tipos de idiomas sem interferir no núcleo do aplicação.

**Localização (l10n)**: É o processo de adaptar uma aplicação internacionalizada para uma especifica região ou idioma com uso de uma localização (locale) especifica e traduções de textos. Fonte [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) (en).

Em tese o termo localização (l10n) é usado como sinônimo de internacionalização (i18n), e globalização é o resumo de ambos os termos.

Para simplificar, O que você deseja é adaptar sua aplicação para suportar outros idiomas, formatos de data, *string*, fuso horário e etc de acordo com a localização (*locale*) do usuário, então você usará o termo **internacionalização**.

#### Configuração:

Para internacionalizar sua aplicação com PHP, basicamente dois aspectos são importantes:

01: você pode definir a função `setlocale()` de acordo com locale definido pelo usuário ou identificado automaticamente pela sua aplicação:

Ex:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf8');
```

Desse modo você vai alterar o formato que o usuário visualiza valor monetário, data, *strings* e etc.

02: Traduzir as *strings* para isso você usará as funções do [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) disponível para dezenas de linguagens e também para o [PHP](http://php.net/gettext).

> NOTA: Não é eficaz traduzir seu site usando `arrays` de *strings* isso causa transtorno para o desenvolvimento de front-end e back-end, além de razões de performance.

Para usar o `gettext` o que você precisa saber se seu servidor suporta esse recurso:

```
if (!function_exists("gettext")){
   echo "gettext não esta instalado\n";
}
else{
   echo "gettext é suportado\n";
}
```

Veja no [manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) como prosseguir com a instalação e configuração do `gettext`.

Após configurar seu servidor sua aplicação esta pronta para ser traduzida. Agora é só prosseguir com o desenvolvimento em suas camadas (MVC) da aplicação normalmente, mas com uma exceção para que `gettext` possa identificar e fazer a tradução você agora usará a função `_()` em suas strings, isso em qualquer camada que essas *strings* aparecerão, *model*, *view* ou *controller*, um ex:

```
echo _("text to be translated");

// ou

echo gettext("text to be translated");
```

#### Tradução das *strings*

Eu recomendo o programa **Poedit** para extrair as *strings* da sua aplicação e gerar seus arquivos `.po` (*Portable Object*) um arquivo de texto contendo suas traduções, um exemplo abaixo:

```
#: test.php:3
english/messages.po:
msgid "Hello World!"
msgstr "Hola Mundo"
```

Esse arquivo pode ser traduzido por qualquer pessoa com ajuda do Poedit ou outro editor. Ao salvar este arquivo será compilado um outro arquivo `.mo` (*Machine Object*) um arquivo binário que o `gettext` usa para leitura e tradução das *strings*.

Com seus `.mo` traduzidos, salve em uma pasta de acordo com cada locale:

Portable Object files

```
.
├── i18n
│   ├── en_US
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── messages.mo
│   ├── en_UK
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── messages.mo
│   └── es_ES
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           └── messages.mo
└── index.php
```

Automaticamente seus textos serão traduzidos de acordo com o locale do usuário.

#### Considerações

Embora à primeira vista o `gettext` parece ser e um pouco complexo, uma vez configurado em seu sistema sua aplicação poderá ser traduzida e atualizada de maneira rápida e eficaz, e ainda permite que outras pessoas que não sejam respectivamente programadores possam trabalhar nas traduções dos arquivos de maneira síncrona e usando apenas um editor de `.po`.

Existem alguns "contras" à essa maneira para internacionalizar aplicação, uma delas é devido os arquivos binários `.mo` ficarem armazenados na memória do servidor cada alteração nos arquivos `.po` você terá que recompilar e gerar novos arquivos `.mo` e com isso reiniciar seu servidor.

#### Alternativas se seu servidor não suporta `gettext`

Como alternativa você pode usar uma library em PHP similar para simular o a função `_()` da mesma maneira que o WordPress usa como fallback caso não exista a função `gettext`. No entanto o uso dessa alternativa resulta consideravelmente a performance do servidor.

Comment: A parte de configuração não era necessária, e você abordou apenas pacotes de tradução e minha questão é justamente sobre **l10n**. Localização vai além de "adaptar uma aplicação internacionalizada", isso é a própria internacionalização.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Eu concordo com a definição do Adriano (e da Wikipedia) sobre os termos. Porém, as definições desses termos não são absolutas, tem pessoas e empresas que os usam conforme suas próprias definições.

Comment: Pois é @bfavaretto, não são absolutas. Mas não concordo com a descrição da **l10n** que foi dada. Até a descrição pela *W3* pode gerar confusão, mas ao meu ver, a **l10n** tem relação com conteúdo regional e não apenas o fato de "adaptar uma aplicação internacionalizada". Mas estou aberto ao debate :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie o assunto é muito bom! realmente causa dúvidas, na minha percepção se o objetivo é tornar um produto/aplicação disponível para outros idiomas e culturas i18n é o termo p/ design/desenvolvimento. Disponibilizar esse produto/conteúdo no formato correcto para o seu alvo, ex: en_UK, en_US, en_AU então o L10n faz sentido, digamos que uma aplicação i18n X esta localizada para pt_BR, pt_PT e en_US, tecnicamente falando disso em PHP é mais ou menos como citei anteriormente, no meu ponto de vista, mas acho vai que mto além, e falando de escala mundial o termo G11n seja mais apropriado.

Comment: Veja o caso do *Google Doodles* que formata o logotipo. Ou quando você acessa um site nacional de notícias e ver o destaque da sua cidade. É a L18n em ação. Meu ponto é esse e não o foco na I18n. Como disse na questão, já tenho a I18n em funcionamento.

Comment: Cara, alguém pode me dar uma luz de como criar um novo PO, para que eu possa abrir no PO edit?